# JQuery - Add css class to List

Tags: jquery, css, list, unordered

I have the following HTML :

```
<li>
<a class="meuble-tab" href="#">Meuble</a>
</li>
```

i need to achieve the following:

```
<li class="active">
<a class="meuble-tab" href="#">Meuble</a>
</li>
```

Using Jquery I am at the point where i can get to the

$(".meuble-tab")

How do I get to its parent "li" to do the addClass("active")?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".meuble-tab").parent("li").addClass("active");
```

For reference, please see [parent( [expr] )](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/parent):

> Get the direct parent of an element.
> If called on a set of elements, parent
> returns a set of their unique direct
> parent elements.
>
> You may use an
> optional expression to filter the
> element(s). If there is no parent,
> returns a jQuery object with a length
> of 0.

Comment: Sorry , it did work, I had a syntax error in my code ! Thanks that was easy - foolish to post a question :)

Comment: I just tried this. It does work. Are you running that code bit in $(document).ready()?

Comment: @redsquare - Otherwise I would need to do this: `$(".meuble-tab").parent(),get(0).addClass("active");` - I figured my approach was more concise,

Answer (score 0):

```
Complete Code :
===============
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul#unlist li").click(function(){
        $("li").removeClass("tbg")
        $(this).addClass("tbg");
    });
});
</script>
<style>
.tbg{
background-color:  green !important;
}
ul li{
display: inline;
padding:10px;
background-color:blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="unlist">
<li class="tbg"><a href="#">one</a></li>
<li><a href="#">two</a></li>
<li><a href="#">three</a></li>
<li><a href="#">four</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For multiple html page load or refresh condition use this different script

Answer (score 0):

```
    Complete Code :
    ===============
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>


    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("li").click(function () {

            var id = $(this).attr("id");

            $('#' + id).siblings().find(".active").removeClass("active");
                //                       ^ you forgot this
            $('#' + id).addClass("active");
            localStorage.setItem("selectedolditem", id);
        });

        var selectedolditem = localStorage.getItem('selectedolditem');

        if (selectedolditem != null) {

            $('#' + selectedolditem).siblings().find(".active").removeClass("active");
            //                                        ^ you forgot this
            $('#' + selectedolditem).addClass("active");
        }
    });
    </script>
    <style>
    .active,.tbg{
    background-color:  green !important;
    }
    ul li{
    display: inline;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:blue;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <ul id="unlist">
<ul id="unlist">
<li id="1" class="active"><a href="addcss.php">one</a></li>
<li id="2"><a href="addcss2.php">two</a></li>
<li id="3"><a href="addcss3.php">three</a></li>
<li id="4"><a href="addcss4.php">four</a></li>
</ul>



</body>
    </html>
```